# Trying to show Count by department in Python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

This is a simple piece of code for some reason I can't think of at the moment. I am trying to get the count of task by status by department. For instance something like this:

```
 Department      Task           Status
   Sales         Sell           Pendiing
   Sales         Presentation   Complete
   Tech          Merge Data     Complete 
   Tech          Consolidate    Pending 
   Tech          Presentation   Complete
```

What I want for here is to be able to break down by department of the count of completed in the status column. Something like this:

```
Department    Status        Count
  Sales       Completed       1
  Tech        Completed       2
```

So far my code sees the count for all departments but I can't figure out the best way to group by.

Code for reference:

```
counts = df['Department'].groupby('Status').count()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) `Department` and `Status`; you can then `count` each group and [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) the `Task` column if desired. Then you can use [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html?highlight=reset_indexe) if required to return a row-indexed dataframe:

```py
df2 = df.groupby(['Department', 'Status']).count().rename(columns={'Task':'Count'}).reset_index()
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
  Department    Status Count
0      Sales  Complete     1
1      Sales  Pendiing     1
2       Tech  Complete     2
3       Tech   Pending     1
```

You can then filter that on `Status` if required:

```py
df2[df2['Status'] == 'Complete']
```

Output:

```
  Department    Status  Count
0      Sales  Complete      1
2       Tech  Complete      2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative which will produce the expected output using [`pandas.GroupBy.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count)

```py
df = df[df['Status'] == 'Complete'].groupby('Department')['Task'].count().reset_index()
df.columns = ['Department', 'Count']

df['Status'] = 'Completed'
df = df.reindex(columns=['Department', 'Status', 'Count'])

print(df)
```

---

```
  Department     Status  Count
0      Sales  Completed      1
1       Tech  Completed      2
```